# @transaction.atomic not working on signals.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

This is my signals.py file

```
@transaction.atomic
def post_save_transaction(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    adjusts the patient or organization account balance on transaction
    """
    if created:
        instance.paid_by.balance -= instance.amount
        instance.accounts.balance += instance.amount
        instance.accounts.save(update_fields=['balance'])
        instance.paid_by.save(update_fields=['balance'])
```

for multiple objects creation at a time this transaction work but it is use the previous balance again.

Comment: What do you mean, "use the previous balance again"?

Comment: I want to update the balance for each transaction. So if I create two objects at a time then it works for this signal but for second it is used the previous paid_by balance not the updated.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-isolation-level